# Failed to open a fast load rowset

Tags: ssis, etl, database-administration, ssis-2008

So I keep getting the following issue when my package is executed

**Description**: "TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  ".

**End Error Error**: 
2018-04-15 21:12:47.60

**Code**: 0xC0202040

**Source**: First Passenger XXXXXX [16]     Description: Failed to open a fastload rowset for "[XXXX].[XXXX]". Check that the object exists in the database.  End Error  Error: 2018-04-15 21:12:47.60

**Code**: 0xC004701A

**Source**: Get First Applicable Passenger SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "XXXXXX" (16) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202040.

**End Error  DTExec**: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  7:19:15 PM  Finished: 9:12:47 PM  Elapsed:  6811.38 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

However, if I manually try to do the job after it fails, it is successful.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "if I manually try to do the job after it fails, it is successful." Do you run the job from the scheduler when you manually run it? Or do you execute the package from the editor?

Answer (score 0):

"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" usually means that the SQL Server was rebooted or the service was stopped and restarted.   Try running your job at a different time, maybe it is being interfered with by some other maintenance job.